# How to hide orders in Woocommerce order list depending on status

Tags: woocommerce

In woocommerce admin order list, is it possible to automatically hide or remove all orders that have not a completed status or pending-payment statut ?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello please check following code to do the things correct

```
add_filter('woocommerce_admin_order_actions','wdm_verify_product_limitation',5,2);
function wdm_verify_product_limitation( $actions, $the_order ){
    if ( $the_order->has_status( array('complete') ) ) {
        unset($actions['pending']);
        unset($actions['on-hold']);
    }
   return $actions;
}
```

Hope this help to solve your problem

Thank You.

Comment: This is not the answer to the original question

Comment: May be this was deprecate due to the newer version.Please check and let me know

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution !

```
add_action('wc_order_statuses', 'my_statuses');

function my_statuses($order_statuses) {

    unset($order_statuses['wc-cancelled']);
    unset($order_statuses['wc-pending']);

    return $order_statuses;
}
```