# Hide orders with status (Pending Payment) on WooCommerce My Account page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Inspired by the thread ['Hiding order status in My Account recent orders list page'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43392110/hiding-order-status-in-my-account-recent-orders-list-page)
 I tried to hide orders with status (Pending Payment) on the 'My Account' page.

I modified the code slightly, but I can't get it to work.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', 'custom_removing_order_status_pending_payment', 10, 1);

function custom_removing_order_status_pending_payment( $order ){
    unset($order['wc-pending']);
    return $order;
}
```

I really appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: This is the filter for the buttons in the 'Action' column (which takes two arguments by the way, $actions and $order). Do you only want to hide the 'View' button or the whole order?

Comment: @Terminator-Barbapapa hide only orders with status (pending payment)

Comment: Yes but hide the whole order row, or only the 'View' button?

Comment: @Terminator-Barbapapa the entire row of orders in status (Pending Payment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you are using the `woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions` filter which will let you filter the buttons in the 'Action' column on the 'My Account' page.

If you want to filter out certain order statuses from the order list you will have to use the `woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query` filter.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 'unset_pending_payment_orders_from_my_account', 10, 1 );
function unset_pending_payment_orders_from_my_account( $args ) {
    $statuses = wc_get_order_statuses();    
    unset( $statuses['wc-pending'] );
    $args['post_status'] = array_keys( $statuses );
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, it works very well, greetings from Venezuela.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can hide the status (Pending Payment) in the order management page?

Comment: Check out this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47571005/how-to-hide-orders-in-woocommerce-order-list-depending-on-status

Comment: Thanks, I already solved it. It wasn't working because I was using the woocommerce order status manager plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is mostly, OK, however, it relies on WooCommerce saving Orders as a WordPress custom post type, and there's been for a while a conversation about moving orders to their own custom table to improve performance and scalability of WooCommerce-powered stores.

As a general rule, it is better to use WooCommerce's specific methods and parameters.

The filter `woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query` uses [wc_get_orders](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query) which says to use `'status'` as parameter, and not `'post_status'`

The updated answer using WC_Order_Query would be

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 'unset_pending_payment_orders_from_my_account', 10, 1 );


function unset_pending_payment_orders_from_my_account( $args ) {
    $statuses = wc_get_order_statuses();    
    unset( $statuses['wc-pending'] );
    $args['status'] = array_keys( $statuses );
    return $args;
}
```